# singleton class method call in Angular 2 onInit vs in method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which hits an api url, gets data in response and displays it in the html.

Just before the request is sent, I need to show a spinner and after I get the response and extract data from it , I should hide it.

The code goes something like this :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    self.loadingProvider.showLoading();//show spinner
    getData();
    self.loadingProvider.hideLoading();
}

getData(){
//code to fetch data from the server
}
```

loadingProvider is a reference to singleton class instance.
Everything is working, except that I don't see the spinner.

Now, when I do it like this, it works perfectly well :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        getData();      
}

getData(){

    self.loadingProvider.showLoading();//show spinner

   //code to fetch data from the server

    self.loadingProvider.hideLoading();
}
```

Can someone please explain it why it doesn't work in ngOnInit but works inside the function ?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just directly hidden? Try to put the hideLoading inside the finish method of your Observable

Comment: If you use `self`, I guess we don't have the whole picture.

Comment: @Paleo my bad. There is a "let self = this;" statement too.

Comment: @Sakuto it works when I call showLoading() before sending request and hideLoading() in the finish method of observable, like you say, but what I am unable to understand is that why is it not working when I try to show before called the getData() method and hide after that, in the ngOnInit() body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is an asynchronous language, meaning that the order of your operation does not really matter, it will not wait that the previous one has finished launching the next.

In your case, it shows the spinner, launch the request and immediately hide it. The solution would be to return the Observable (or a promise from it) and then hide the spinner in the .then() method of your Promise.

Add `.toPromise()` to the end of your Observable and return it, and in your ngInit do something like:

```
self.loadingProvider.showLoading().then(() =>
    self.loadingProvider.hideLoading();
);
```